# A Dark Room No Huts Challenge

Tags: a-dark-room

If you do the no huts challenge when does the script first change? I looked at many other websites but I could not find the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you might be able to look into the game script and try to figure it out (but don't quote me on that)

Answer (score -2):

pretty sure its the builder's seizure after i think the smokehouse, might be the workshop.